# Shortcut in Visual Studio Code to return back

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

Is there any shortcut in Visual Studio Code to return back like the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> (forward/backward) in intellij?

Comment: It's Alt-F12. Like in Visual Studio :)

Comment: the Alt-F12 shortcut is to show definition

Comment: F12 - showing definition, Alt-F12 goes backward :)

Comment: Try Alt + Left arrow for previous pane and Alt+ Right Arrow for next pane. Or refer full shortcuts at File -> Preferences->Keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: That's what I was looking for @Shinchan thank you! you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Alt + Left arrow for previous pane and Alt+ Right Arrow for next pane. 
Or refer full shortcuts at File -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts